# Find a closed form to $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k3^{n-k}$

Tags: summation

How would I find the closed form of

$\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k3^{n-k}$

There's two properties of summations that I think apply here:

$\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb^{i+k}=b^{i}\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb^{k}$

and

$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$

How do I apply them?

Comment: Note that $$
2^k 3^{n - k}  = 3^n \left( {\frac{2}{3}} \right)^k 
$$ and that $3^n$ is independent of $k$.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. That you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can use the  high-school formula:
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\biggl( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^k\biggr)$$